# SQL Server LocalDB column error when deployed to Tablet PC

Tags: c#, localdb, tablet-pc

I am getting a

> System.AgumentException: Column 'BarcodeStr' does not belong to table

when I deploy the C# application from the development PC running Windows 10 to a tablet PC running Windows 10.

My application is a C# Windows Forms application with an embedded LocalDb v11.0. On the development PC, it is connecting without a problem but when I deploy it, I get that error.

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB\StockTakeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

The issue seems to be coming from this line:

```
int intScanned = dtStockTake.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r ["BarcodeStr"].ToString().Trim().Length > 0 && !r["BarcodeStr"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("BUNDLE-0-LABEL")).Select(x => x["BarcodeStr"].ToString()).ToList().Distinct().ToList().Count();
```

Comment: `LocalDB` is a developer-oriented version of SQL Server **Express** - which is really **NOT** an "embedded" database - it requires an installation on the target machine before it can run there.....

Comment: Thanks @Marc_s, how do I install it without installing SQL Server on tablet

Comment: You **cannot** - if you want to use `LocalDB`, then you **must** install the `LocalDB` package (which is the dev-oriented SQL Server version)

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, will try sqlce then